Image upload using Uploadthing returns undefined when the form is submitted
//image-uploader.tsx
"use client"
interface ImageUploadProps {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
  onRemove: (value: string) => void;
  value: string[];
}

const ImageUpload: React.FC<ImageUploadProps> = ({
  onChange,
  onRemove,
  value,
}) => {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  const onUpload = (result: any) => {
    onChange(result.url);
  };

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
       <div className="flex flex-col content-center w-fit gap-y-2">
          <div>
            <div>
              {value.map((url) => (
                <div
                  key={url}
                >
                  <div className="z-10 absolute top-1 right-1">
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => onRemove(url)}
                      variant="destructive"
                    >
                      <Trash className="h-3 w-3" />
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  <Image fill className="object-cover" alt="" src={url} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <UploadButton
            className="ut-button:bg-accent ut-button:text-black dark:ut-button:text- 
    white ut-button:h-9"
            onClientUploadComplete={onUpload}
            onUploadError={() => {
              toast.error("Oops! Something went wrong");
            }}
            endpoint="imageUploader"
          />
     </div>
  );
};

 export default ImageUpload;

 //form.tsx

 import ImageUpload from "@/components/ui/image-upload";


 const formSchema = z.object({
   name: z.string().min(1),
   images: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array().min(1),
 });

 type TemplateFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

 export const Form = () => {
   const form = useForm<TemplateFormValues>({
   resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
 )}

 return (
    <Form {...form}>
    <form
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className="space-y-8 w-full"
    >
      ...
      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="images"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Images</FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <ImageUpload
                value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)}
                  onChange={(url) =>
                     field.onChange([...field.value, { url }])
                  }
                  onRemove={(url) =>
                    field.onChange([
                      ...field.value.filter(
                        (current) => current.url !== url
                      ),
                    ])
                  }
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
         </FormItem>
       )}
     />
     <Button
       type="submit"
     >
       Submit
     </Button>
    </form>
  </Form>
)

I am building an app with React and using UploadThing for file storage, and I am trying to submit the form. Still, the field of name images gives a zod validation error of undefined, and the image is there but does not display anything(picture below). I have used the same image-uploader component in the past with Cloudinary, and it worked fine. My guess is the onUpload function might be the problem, but I've spent a while on this, but still haven't figured it out.
Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

